# dont want return children on get list mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, reactjs, mongoose

I Have A Category Schema With Children Property That Use `ObjectId` with `ref:Category` Like This :

```
const category = new Schema({
   title : {type : String},
   children : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}]
},{collection : 'Category'});
```

And I Create Chilrend And Parent And Every Thing is OK...
my Problem is when i get list of `category` children too returend seprate with parent :

```
    const children = new category({
         title : "children",
         childrent :  []
      })
    const parent = new category({
         title : "parent",
         childrent :  [children._id]
      })

====================================================================

category.find({},(err,result)=>{
     console.log("result",result)
})

//output

[
 {
  _id : "asdasdsadasd", ///my problem is here i dont want return childs that have parent !
   title : "children",
   childrent :  []
  },
  {
  _id : "tttttttttttt",
   title : "parent",
   childrent :  [{
        _id : "asdasdsadasd",
        title : "children",
        childrent :  []
  }]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same schema, so both parents and children are inserted to the same collection - and are thus being returned by your 'find all' query. You should separate your parent categories and child categories in different schemas IMHO.

Another approach would be to set a type:

`categoryType: {type: String, enum: ['parent','child'], required: true}`

and use that to differentiate your categories, then you would query:
`category.find({categoryType: 'child'})` or 'parent' to find only parents or children.!

Comment: tnx but i dont want use two collection and type...i search for handle that without this ways

Comment: Ok, so another solution would be to omit the `children: []` from your childs, and adjust your query: `{ children: {$exists: false} }`    Bear in mind that you have labeled them `childrent` in your example :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the field when you are doing query to find category. Try following:

```
category.find({},{children : 0},(err,result)=>{
     console.log("result",result)
});
```

Refer [project-doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-document) for more info.

Comment: Is there any issue or error you are getting? What is the output you got after running the query?